# Can we search or filter " data-tag='to-do' " in onenote API ? If yes then how we can do this?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

How can we use OneNote tags (like `data-tag='to-do'`) with search or filter in OneNote API. I tried using provide operators but found no success.

I tried in this way --

```
    $url = "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes";
    //$url .= "/pages?search=hello";
    $url .= "/pages?filter=data-tag eq 'to-do'";
```

I want to search data-tag and then extract the data from OneNote pages which contains the data-tag='to-do'.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run through all your pages.

For each pages, you can retrieve its content with a `GET` call to `https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages/%s/content?includeIds=true`

From there you get a string that you can parse.

I'll advise you to use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

With jsoup you can then write (assuming `content`contains your page's content):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
Elements todos=doc.select("[data-tag^=\"to-do\"]");

for(Element todo:todos) {
    System.out.println(todo.ownText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly OneNote API doesn't support it yet, so I've written my custom parser which extracts notes with data-tags from page content. Here it is:

```
public class OneNoteParser
    {
        static public List<Note> ExtractTaggedNotes(string pageContent, string tag = "*")
        {
            List<Note> allNotes = new List<Note>();

            string[] dataTagString = { "data-tag=\""};

            string[] dirtyNotes = pageContent.Split(dataTagString, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            //First one in this array can be dropped as it doesn't contain todo
            for (int i = 1; i < dirtyNotes.Length; i  )
            {
                string curStr = dirtyNotes[i];
                Note curNote = new Note();

                // Firstly we need to extract all the tags from it (sample html: data-tag="to-do:completed,important" ....)
                string allTags = curStr.Substring(0,curStr.IndexOf("\""));

                curNote.Tags = new List<string>(allTags.Split(','));

                // Now we have to jump to the next ">" symbol and start finding the text after it
                curStr = curStr.Substring(curStr.IndexOf(">"));

                int depth = 1;
                bool addAllowed = false;

                for (int j = 0; j < curStr.Length - 1; j  )
                {
                    // Finding next tag opener "<" symbol
                    if (curStr[j] == '<')
                    {
                        addAllowed = false;

                        // Checking if it is not "</" closer
                        if (curStr[j   1] == '/')
                        {
                            // Means this is a tag closer. Decreasing depth
                            depth--;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Means this is an tag opener. Increasing depth
                            depth  ;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (curStr[j] == '>')
                    {
                        addAllowed = true;

                        if (j > 0 && curStr[j - 1] == '/')
                        {
                            // Means this is a tag closer. Decreasing depth
                            depth--;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (depth < 1)
                        {
                            // Found end of the tag. Saving index and exiting for loop
                            break;
                        }

                        if (addAllowed)
                            curNote.Text  = curStr[j]; // Appending letter to string
                    }
                }

                // Filtering by tag and adding to final list
                if (tag == "*" || curNote.Tags.Any(str => str.Contains(tag)))//curNote.Tags.Contains(tag, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        allNotes.Add(curNote);

            }
            return allNotes;
        }
    }
```

And here is the class `Note`

```
   public class Note
    {
        public string Text;
        public List<string> Tags;
        public Note()
        {
            Tags = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

To extract todo-s simply call this function:

```
OneNoteParser.ExtractTaggedNotes(pageContent, "to-do");
```

Also you can extract other tags like this:

```
OneNoteParser.ExtractTaggedNotes(pageContent, "important");
OneNoteParser.ExtractTaggedNotes(pageContent, "highlight");
//...
```